# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in python

Tags: python, function, recursion

I am trying to make power function by recursion. 
But I got run time error like Maximum recursion depth exceeded.
I will appreciate any help!!
Here is my code.

```
 def fast_power(a,n):
    if(n==0):
        return 1
    else:
       if(n%2==0):
           return fast_power(fast_power(a,n/2),2)
       else:
           return fast_power(fast_power(a,n/2),2)*a
```

Comment: This is why using recursion in a non-purely-functional language is generally a bad idea unless you know for sure it's not going to run for a long time.

Comment: You call the same function twice for every time it's called once. This will explode and take exponential memory while it runs. Are you sure the algorithm is right?

Comment: @Carcigenicate The algorithm is correct. It uses the fact that `x^2n == (x^n)^2`.  However the `^2` could be replaced by a multiplication: `x = fast_power(a, n//2); return x*x`

Comment: @Carcigenicate In any case the problem causing the recursion exceeded error is the use of `/` to divide, as shown in my answer. The algorithm should only use integers and thus it should use integer division `//` and not `/`.

Comment: @Bakuriu OK. I don't know the algorithm, so that's what stood out to me.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you so much!! It works!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `n // 2` instead of `n / 2`:

```
>>> 5 // 2
2
>>> 5 / 2
2.5
```

(At least in python3)

The problem is that once you end up with floats it takes quite a while before you end up at `0` by dividing by `2`:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> n = 5
>>> for i in count():
...     n /= 2
...     if n == 0:
...         break
... 
>>> i
1076
```

So as you can see you would need more than 1000 recursive calls to reach `0` from `5`, and that's above the default recursion limit. Besides: that algorithm is meant to be run with integer numbers.

---

This said I'd write that function as something like:

```
def fast_power(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    tmp = fast_power(a, n//2)
    tmp *= tmp
    return a*tmp if n%2 else tmp
```

Which produces:

```
>>> fast_power(2, 7)
128
>>> fast_power(3, 7)
2187
>>> fast_power(13, 793)
22755080661651301134628922146701289018723006552429644877562239367125245900453849234455323305726135714456994505688015462580473825073733493280791059868764599730367896428134533515091867511617127882942739592792838327544860344501784014930389049910558877662640122357152582905314163703803827192606896583114428235695115603966134132126414026659477774724471137498587452807465366378927445362356200526278861707511302663034996964296170951925219431414726359869227380059895627848341129113432175217372073248096983111394024987891966713095153672274972773169033889294808595643958156933979639791684384157282173718024930353085371267915606772545626201802945545406048262062221518066352534122215300640672237064641040065334712571485001684857748001990405649808379706945473443683240715198330842716984731885709953720968428395490414067791229792734370523603401019458798402338043728152982948501103056283713360751853
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Bakuriu's explanation of the problem is incomplete.  Not his reimplementation, but his explanation of your bug(s).  You might convince yourself of this by replacing `/` with `//` in your original code and try:

```
fast_power(2, 2)
```

it still exceeds the stack.  Try expanding the stack ten fold:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

it still exceeds the stack. The reason is you also have an infinte loop:

```
if (n % 2 == 0):
    return fast_power(..., 2)
```

Since 2 % 2 == 0, this simply keeps recursing forever.  Adding another base case:

```
if n == 2:
    return a * a
```

fixes the problem.  A complete solution:

```
def fast_power(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1

#   if n == 1:
#       return a

    if n == 2:
        return a * a

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return fast_power(fast_power(a, n // 2), 2)

    return a * fast_power(fast_power(a, n // 2), 2)
```